# Cannot find a class in RealBasic - RealUnzip

Tags: realbasic

This is a probably a really simple fix, but I'm extremely new to RealBasic and I'm having difficulty finding help.

`dim objUnZipIt as new  RealUnzip`

The error I keep getting is :

There is no class with this name: di objUnZipIt as new **RealUnzip**

I'm attempting to debug something in a language I don't know, and the original developer is long gone. Where can I find the library? Or possibly make a small alteration to get this running?

Thank you very much.

Edit: Ok, digging through the folders I found a RealZip.dll . Any idea how I can import this ?

Comment: A great place for finding RealBasic help is the [RB forums](http://forums.realsoftware.com). Lots RB of developers are there including some of RealSoftware's engineers and plugin maintainers.

Comment: Cool. I might need that. There's a lot of issues coming up with this code and I assume it's because of the transition from old to new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RealZip plugin was provided by a third-party developer whose website has been offline for several years. You can still grab the plugin from [the Internet Archive's copy of their site](http://web.archive.org/web/20061210164306/http://www.control-d.co.uk/download.htm).

Extract the .rbx file into the `plugins` sub-directory of the REALstudio install directory and restart the IDE. Since this plugin is no longer maintained, there may be issues with using it in a modern version of the IDE (the included demo project works, though, with only a deprecation warning unrelated to the plugin.)

There's also a [GZip plugin available on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/realbasicgzip/) (similarly unmaintained) and the commercial [MonkeyBread Compression plugin](http://www.monkeybreadsoftware.net/example-compression-zip.shtml) which is actively maintained.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. That helped a lot, now on to the next problems…

Comment: I don't hate RealBasic, but I'm probably going to have to rewrite this into a language I know better, but stepping through the running code will help solve my immediate problem of where it's breaking.

Comment: RealBasic is a great language, but its third-party plugin ecosystem is necrotic.

Comment: I got another bug. DesktopFolder.AbsolutePath. Object doesn't exist, does this sound like another plugin ?

Comment: No, a [deprecation](http://docs.realsoftware.com/index.php/Deprecations_in_Real_Studio#2011_Release_1). Replace `DesktopFolder.AbsolutePath` with `SpecialFolder.Desktop.AbsolutePath`

Comment: thanks! This project looks like it hasn't been touched since 2008. It's probably written on a platform that's older than that.